# What modifications were made to the Tiger Moth by Brains?

Tags: thunderbirds

At the end of Thunderbird 6, we learn that the new Thunderbird is in fact a Tiger Moth.  But surely some alterations would have been made to it.  Does anyone know of any of Brains' modifications (and I mean besides the paintwork!)

[image: Thunderbird 6 (which looks suspiciously like a normal tiger moth...]

Comment: I am a reasonably big fan of Thunderbirds and after reviewing the movie recently, I found no evidence of *any* modifications, apart from the paint work :P.  The Thunderbirds Wiki doesn't have much to help either.  Any other sources I could try that come to mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like there were any modifications made to the aircraft, either in-universe or out-of-universe (aside from the obligatory upgrade of safety features).

The short featurette "[Thunderbird 6 : Tiger Moth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1135065/)" describes the Director David Lane's thinking:

> "
>   [my transcript]*It was felt that we'd done the one with the hardware, and we now
>   wanted to do something that was amusing. Up came this script with a
>   Tiger Moth in it, **which was as far removed from the hardware that
>   was in Thunderbirds as anything I can think of.***
>
> *You know, it was just an old bi-plane from World War I."*

At the end of the film, the plane is redesignated [Thunderbird 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbird_6) (complete with new paintjob) but then never appears in any other films or shows.

The most obvious suggestion is that this was intended to be an International Rescue "[family-joke](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InJoke)", basically making the plane a team-mascot.